# Get field values from class within class

Tags: c#, reflection

This has been driving me mad for a while now. I have a class which contains other classes. I need to loop through the first class looking for typeof second class then retreive the value of the fields.

the below code obviously fails on the line

```
Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(mFC.field.secondClassString));
```

as this isn't a valid field. Possibly I'm going about this the wrong way - any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyFirstClass mFC = new MyFirstClass();

            FieldInfo[] fI = mFC.GetType().GetFields();

            foreach (FieldInfo field in fI)
            {
                if (field.FieldType.Name == "MySecondClass")
                {
                    //get the fields
                    Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(mFC.field.secondClassString));                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class MyFirstClass
    {
        public MySecondClass firstMSC = new MySecondClass("First Instance");
        public MySecondClass secondMSC = new MySecondClass("Second Instance");
        public string firstClassString = "I'm from the first class";
        public int firstClassInt = 5;
    }

    class MySecondClass
    {
        public MySecondClass(string input)
        {
            this.secondClassString = input;
        }
        public string secondClassString;
        public int secondClassInt = 10;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

((MySecondClass)field.GetValue(mFC)).secondClassString;

use this inside console.writeline

Comment: Thats the one! needed casting to the inner class. thanks

Comment: I was orginally trying to cast the entire field back to a surface object. How would I do this.. e.g. MySecondClass newClass = (MySecondClass).field.....

Comment: MySecondClass c = (MySecondClass)field.GetValue(mFC);                           you can do this

Comment: It's really strange, if I add this to my code, the object isn't created, just moves to next line. If however I paste the same code into Immediate window, the object is created

Answer (score 2):

`field.GetValue` accepts the instance from which it gets the field value.
In your case I would expect it should be `field.GetValue(mFC)`.

Also `field.FieldType.Name == "MySecondClass"` is not the best way to check the type as type name change will cause code to break. I recommend replacing it with `field.FieldType == typeof(MySecondClass)`.